# Not saving a new bitmap c#

Tags: c#, bitmap

I am wanting to show the new bitmap image thats been created. Not save it.

Im using bitmap with graphics in C# and im hoping to return the new image without having to save a new image.

**C#**

```
private void GenerateBanner( string titleText ) {

    Bitmap bannerSource = new Bitmap( DefaultBannerPath );
    //bannerSource.Save( PhysicalBannerPath );
    RectangleF rectf = new RectangleF( 430, 50, 650, 50 );

    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bannerSource))
    {
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
        g.DrawString(titleText, new Font("Bradley Hand ITC", 100, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.White, rectf);
        //bannerSource.Save( PhysicalBannerPath );
    }
}
```

Comment: Winforms? Use a `PictureBox` on a `Form`

Comment: please say if you are using WinForms or WPF?

Comment: its my own class control. it will be on an aspx page. @FredrikRedin

Comment: Change `private void GenerateBanner( string titleText )` to `private Bitmap GenerateBanner( string titleText )` and add `return bannerSource ` at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return this image from an ASPX page (can be used as `img src` in HTML), you'll need to use a `MemoryStream` and convert it to `byte[]`; then use the `Response.BinaryWrite` method:

```
        byte[] bytes;
        using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            bannerSource.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            bytes = stream.ToArray();
        }

        Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        Response.Clear();
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.End();
```

Comment: _Some detail information_: You need to create a `<img src="getimage.aspx?id=123">` in your html page and the `getimage.aspx` should run the above code. So you need to implement it in two steps. The first is generating an image link. The second is interpreting the querystring to return the right image.